# Fixing non types

Tags: python, list, set

I'm writing a code to keep track of medals won by countries that is returned as a list of strings. Format example:

```
"COUNTRY G S B"
```

Here is my code so far:

```
def generate(results):
    """
    return list of strings
    based on data in results, a list of strings
    """

    #  [country_code, gold_count, silver_count, bronze_count ]
    allCountries = []
    for i in results:
        x = i.split()
        for country in x:
            allCountries.append(country)
    allCountries = set(allCountries)
    medalTracker = []
    medalTracker = [medalTracker.append(i) for i in allCountries]
    # medalTracker = list(medalTracker)
    for i in medalTracker:
        goldCount, silverCount, bronzeCount = 0, 0, 0
        Idx = medalTracker.index(i)
        medalTracker[Idx].append(goldCount, silverCount, bronzeCount)
        for rank in results:
            if rank [1] == i:
                goldCount += 1
            elif rank [2] == i:
                silverCount += 1
            elif rank[3] == i:
                bronzeCount += 1

print(generate(["ITA JPN AUS", "KOR TPE UKR", "KOR KOR GBR", "KOR CHN TPE"]))
```

should return:

```
[ "KOR 3 1 0",  "ITA 1 0 0",  "TPE 0 1 1",  "CHN 0 1 0",  "JPN 0 1 0",  
  "AUS 0 0 1",  "GBR 0 0 1",  "UKR 0 0 1" ]
```

I'm getting a non Type error on line 20:

```
medalTracker[Idx].append(goldCount, silverCount, bronzeCount)
```

I'm not sure why.
Can anyone explain how I would be able to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check `medalTracker`. It holds Nones. Why are you appending in a list comprehension?

Comment: `medalTracker = [medalTracker.append(i) for i in allCountries]` is same as `medalTracker = list(allCountries)` ;)

Comment: Did you mean `medalTracker = list(allCountries)`?

Comment: @azro not quite, `[i for i in allCountries]` would be equivalent

Comment: @azro Nope, `medalTracker` will be all `None`s.  Not equivalent.

Comment: Don't see the None value haha, leave you for this post :D

Comment: Is your intent just to create a shallow copy of `allCountries`?

Comment: `medalTracker.appends(i)` returns `None` but appends the list in its place. This is what is causing you an error.

Comment: I think you probably want medalTracker to be a `dictionary` which holds the values of `allCountries` as `keys` and values in `results` as their `values`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it is generally frowned upon to use capital letters for anything but classes. Moving on...

```
medalTracker = [medalTracker.append(i) for i in allCountries]
```

The problem is stemming from this line which returns a list of None's

```
<class 'list'>: [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

There are a few other issues namely trying to append some data to a string. Please take a look at this code I think it will give you the results that you are looking for

```
def generate(results):
"""
return list of strings
based on data in results, a list of strings
"""

#  [country_code, gold_count, silver_count, bronze_count ]
allCountries = []
for i in results:
    x = i.split()
    for country in x:
        allCountries.append(country)
allCountries = list(set(allCountries))
medalTracker = []
# medalTracker = list(medalTracker)
for i in allCountries:
    goldCount, silverCount, bronzeCount = 0, 0, 0
    index = allCountries.index(i)
    for rank in results:
        rank = rank.split(' ')
        if rank[0] == i:
            goldCount += 1
        elif rank[1] == i:
            silverCount += 1
        elif rank[2] == i:
            bronzeCount += 1
    medalTracker.append({i: {'goldCount': goldCount, 'silverCount': silverCount, 'bronzeCount': bronzeCount}})

print(generate(["ITA JPN AUS", "KOR TPE UKR", "KOR KOR GBR", "KOR CHN TPE"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You had a couple of issues with your code:

- Your medalTracker list had None values. You could just use list(allCountries) to generate the list
- You were appending to the medalTracker values which are strings.
- You didn't update the medal counts after the rank calculations in medalTracker
- You were comparing the first letter of the country with the full name so the medals were always at 0 value

Here is an updated working version

```
def generate(results):
    """
    return list of strings
    based on data in results, a list of strings
    """

    #  [country_code, gold_count, silver_count, bronze_count ]
    allCountries = []
    for i in results:
        x = i.split()
        for country in x:
            allCountries.append(country)

    medalTracker = list(set(allCountries))
    for i in medalTracker:
        goldCount, silverCount, bronzeCount = 0, 0, 0
        Idx = medalTracker.index(i)
        for rank in results:
            ranks = rank.split()
            if ranks[0] == i:
                goldCount += 1
            elif ranks[1] == i:
                silverCount += 1
            elif ranks[2] == i:
                bronzeCount += 1

        medalTracker[Idx] = medalTracker[Idx] + " " + str(goldCount) + " " + str(silverCount) + " " + str(bronzeCount)
    return medalTracker

print(generate(["ITA JPN AUS", "KOR TPE UKR", "KOR KOR GBR", "KOR CHN TPE"]))
```

Output

```
['TPE 0 1 1', 'JPN 0 1 0', 'UKR 0 0 1', 'CHN 0 1 0', 'ITA 1 0 0', 'AUS 0 0 1', 'GBR 0 0 1', 'KOR 3 0 0']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem exists in this line:

`medalTracker = [medalTracker.append(i) for i in allCountries]`

When you `append` a `list`, it modifies the `list` in place but returns `None`.  You can see a little bit more clearer what happens here:

```
allCountries = ['ITA', 'JPN', 'AUS', 'KOR', 'TPE']   # This is essentially the shorter equivalent of your list.

medalTracker = []

def show_medalTracker_detail():
    print(f'medalTracker id: {id(medalTracker)}, values: {medalTracker}')

def peek(x):
    result = medalTracker.append(x)
    show_medalTracker_detail()
    return result
```

When you run it:

```
>>> show_medalTracker_detail()

medalTracker id: 52731616, values: []

>>> medalTracker = [peek(i) for i in allCountries]

medalTracker id: 52731616, values: ['ITA']
medalTracker id: 52731616, values: ['ITA', 'JPN']
medalTracker id: 52731616, values: ['ITA', 'JPN', 'AUS']
medalTracker id: 52731616, values: ['ITA', 'JPN', 'AUS', 'KOR']
medalTracker id: 52731616, values: ['ITA', 'JPN', 'AUS', 'KOR', 'TPE']

>>> show_medalTracker_detail()

medalTracker id: 52736448, values: [None, None, None, None, None]
```

Notice how the `medalTracker` object id and values have changed after your list comprehension? It's because after the list comprehension finished looping and appending, it also created a list of `None`s and is reassigning that list (a new object) to replace your existing `medalTracker`.

The solution is either just use `medalTracker = list(allCountries)`, or if you want to append, then use a for loop:

```
for i in allCountries:
    medalTracker.append(i)
```